# How configure Django logging to file for app

Tags: django, logging, celery, django-apps

I am struggling with Django logging configuration. I have one app called "api" and I want to save to file all logs from this app. When I set up a logger to django everything works fine but when I change it to my app_name it doesn't.
Here is my configuration:

File structure:

```
email_api
    api
        tasks.py
    email_api
        celery.py
        settings
    logs
        email.log
```

My logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/email.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'api': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

tasks.py file where I logging:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=3, max_retries=3,)
def send_email(self, data, email_id):
    message = create_message(data, email)
    try:
        logger.debug("Log Message Here")
        message.send()
```

Answer (score 2):

Keys in the `LOGGING['loggers'][...]` `dict` are names of loggers. You have configured logging with `api` as a name of the logger.

In order to write to this logger, you should request it by that name:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('api')

...

logger.debug("Log Message Here")
```

Comment: Alternatively, rename your logger from `api` to `email_api`.